# Формула нахождения количества экспрессов в зависимости от размера системы

Tags: математика

Для системы букмекерских ставок нужна **формула расчёта числа экспрессов** в зависимости от количества исходов и событий (размер системы). Например, размер системы: **2 из 3**, тогда число экспрессов будет **3** (события 1 и 2, 1 и 3, 2 и 3). Размер системы: **3 из 5 - 10**, **3 из 7 - 35** и т.д.

Калькулятор ставок, работающий по этой системе: https://info.parimatch.com/calc
Подробное описание системы ставок: https://legalbet.ru/shkola-bettinga/odinochnaya-ekspress-sistema/

Мне нужна лишь формула зависимости между 2 числами для нахождения третьего.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: Число сочетаний, что ли?

Comment: Akina, да, можно и так назвать